# Why the web.config isn't copied when I publish an ASP.NET Web Project with the "Only files needed to run this application" option?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-config

How to correct it?

Comment: In general, I prefer NOT to copy the Web.config file when I publish a web project, since usually I want a totally different web.config on my local machine from what I have on my server.

Comment: Any chance you could improve the contents of this question. ( If this was asked like this now, it would have been closed )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Only files needed to run this application" means any build output files like DLLs and references in the bin folder and any files that have a Build Action of Content.

Since the web.config is neither of these, you'll have to change the publish option to All Project Files, or else copy the web.config manually.

Comment: Just small addition to the answer: Special care is required when renaming `web.config` because `BuildAction` is transferred! I found myself into this trouble when I renamed existing `web.config` to `web.prod.config` and copied in an external `web.config` outside VS ... `BuildAction` of new `web.config` was `None` and `web.prod.config` was `Content`

Answer (score 9):

When you say 'ASP.NET web project', do you mean 'ASP.NET web application project'?

If so, the web.config should have a build action of **Content** by default.  As Brandon mentioned, Content is then copied over to the publish destination.

To verify, select the web.config file in your Solution Explorer then use the Properties Window.  An example:

[example http://photos.tiredstudent.com/WebStorageHandler.ashx?tb=false&id=558](http://photos.tiredstudent.com/WebStorageHandler.ashx?tb=false&id=558)

Answer (score 6):

I know it sounds silly but make sure it is marked as 'Content' as it's Build Action under it's properties.