# Problems with Razor to render a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I'm entering in a specific module of my system, I'm receiving the following error:

> HttpCompileException:
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\f9a69f24\bf43f34d\App_Web_search.cshtml.5571bf69.aspbf3uv.0.cs(35):
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'customWebViewPage' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'Project.Areas.Shared.Code.ViewPage' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

This class: customWebViewPage, does not exist in my project, I searched for this class in all projects and web.config(s) and I did not found anything about her.

I cleaned the .NET temp folder, reset IIS, and the problem still happens.

Does someone have a idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to delete the temporary asp.net files and clean + rebuild your solution and see.

Comment: I did it, I removed the project folder, download of the TFS again and rebuild. But not solved the problem :\

Comment: @RenatoLeite I see it's inside an Area, you did look inside the web.config in the area right? (it has a separate one) Are you working on code someone else wrote or something?

Comment: Is it on the file system but not part of the project?

Comment: I looked and don't have. This problem not happend in my computer, just when I publish on the server.

Comment: In that case, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1306515/3410196) might be related.

Comment: When you publish to the target server do you do a complete overwrite of files or simply publish over top? If you just publish over top does that file then exist on the target server?