# Exclude web.config from server when publishing website (not WAP) VS2005

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, web-config, vs-web-site-project

How do I exclude Web.config from server when publishing website (not web application project) in Visual Studio 2005 
I can see information how to add setting to the Web.Config but in this instance the Web.config is fine on the servers; so I do not want the problem of introducing possible faulty Web.config to a live environment.

Comment: I deleted my answer, Build Action isn't available on a website, it is in a WAP

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude web.config when publishing with Visual Web Developer Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288858/how-to-exclude-web-config-when-publishing-with-visual-web-developer-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply. Go to properties of web.config, for 'Build Action' select 'None' and 'Copy To Output Directory' select 'Do Not copy'