# Web.Config file corrupting on publish

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005, web-config, connection-string

So I've just started up my most recent website: http://EpicClanWars.com

and it would seem that every 5th or 6th time I publish my project out of VS 2005 the Web.Config file corrupts and loses its connection string to the database and a nasty exception gets thrown stating that the web.config file does not contain the connection string that all of my SQLDataSource objects use.

I found this unanswered question that would also fix the issue: [Exclude web.config from server when publishing website (not WAP) VS2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389041/exclude-web-config-from-server-when-publishing-website-not-wap-vs2005)

But I'd rather know if there were some sort of simple fix for this that I don't know about.

Comment: Are you using a Web Application Project or a Web Site Project?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your program saves on your web.config, and when you make updates you corrupt it.

I suggest to open the app_offline.htm when you make updates, after the updates close it again.