# ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment not working in publish profile

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to exclude a folder in publish profile using ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment but it is not wxcluding while publishing to azure-app service

folder location : a\b\c\foldername

Please let me know if anyone can help!!

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use XAML build or v-next build to publish to azure-app service? How's your build definition look? If you publish locally without TFS, is ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment working?

Answer (score 10):

Add an additional answer, in case someone got confused by different EXCLUDE methodologies, if you are working in this environment:

**Visual Studio 2017 + ASP.NET core 2 + Azure App Service.**

try this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.1#exclude-files

Edit `YourProject.csproj` file,

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Update="wwwroot/content/**/*.txt" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
</ItemGroup>
```

BTW, I also tried these posts, which do not work:

1. use `.wpp.targets` file: [Excluding Files and Folders from Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment)
2. Use `Web Deploy Profile`: [Exclude unwanted binaries from azure package](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7360a71c-136e-46e6-8c5a-beaad57c918a/how-to-exclude-unwanted-binaries-from-azure-package?forum=msbuild)
3. Use `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment` or `ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment`: [Web Deployment: Excluding Files and Folders via the Web Application’s Project File](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-applications-project-file/)

By all those methods,  `web.config` could not be excluded, even following this post:
[How to exclude web.config when publishing with Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025340/how-to-exclude-web-config-when-publishing-with-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#can_i_exclude_specific_files_or_folders_from_deployment) article, you need to edit the .pubxml or the .wpp.targets file and add an **ExcludeFilesFromDeployment** element or an **ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment** element (or both) in the **PropertyGroup** element. Check whether you have correct setting as the example shows:

```
<PropertyGroup">
  <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
    File1.aspx;File2.aspx
  </ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    Folder1;Folder2
  </ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Another option to exclude files or folders is to use the PublishIgnore NuGet package. This option is explained in [Web Publishing a simpler way to exclude files/folders from being published](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/08/22/web-publishing-a-simpler-way-to-exclude-filesfolders-from-being-published/) on the .NET Web Development and Tools blog.

Comment: tried this also, I am able to exclude other folders from this method but stuck with one folder. looking if there is any other issue because ExcludeFilesFromDeployment is working with other folders expect one.

Comment: Kindly post an answer when you find out the root cause.

Comment: Do you find the root cause for the particular folder?

Answer (score 0):

In order to exclude folders from a Blazor hosted app (like a PWA) you need to add the exclusion to the *Client* project, not to the *Server*.

I.e., you have a solution with a project named **Server** and a project named **Client**.
The Client.csproj should contains the exclusion, like:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Update="wwwroot\images\contents\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Now, the `wwwroot` folder created by the **Server.pubxml** will not contains the `images/contents` folder and sulfolders.

Answer (score -1):

I was also struggling with the issue and after looking at the @Dongdong answer I came to following conclusion:
Edit `YourProject.csproj` file and include the following

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <Content Update="web.Debug.config;web.Release.config;web.QA.config;appsettings.Debug.json;appsettings.Release.json;" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

You can also apply some condition as well.

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <Content Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='QA|AnyCPU'" Update="appsettings.json;" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

You can extend it as per your requirement. Excluded files from the directory won't be published.

Comment: This applies to files, not folders.