# How to exclude the App_Data folder from being published in an ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-5

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core 5 project using FTP. However, I do not want to publish the `App_Data` folder.

Using Visual Studio 2017, I opened the `.csproj` file and added the following

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="App_Data" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
      <Content Update="App_Data">
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="App_Data" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I also added

```
<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>App_Data</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
```

to the `.pubxml` file.

That did not work.

How can I exclude the `App_Data` entirely from being published?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? ASP.net needs the App_Data directory to store application data for the web process. Is your intention to break the application?

Comment: Possible dupe : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57524961

Comment: @JHBonarius I don't want the local files found in App_Data from my local machine to override the files in production when I deploy via FTP

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527057/7687666)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to exclude the folder in Visual Studio, like the image below.

**After testing, the App_Data folder will not be included when publishing again.**

[image]