# Prevent overwriting of a file when deploying?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, iis, webdeploy

**NOTE: This is for a Visual Studio Web Site Project and NOT a Web Application**

I am using web deploy to push changes from my development machine to my staging server.  I would like to push any files that are different to the staging server except for one particular file (lets call it myFile.whatever)

So far I have tried editing the `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe.config` file to look like so:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <rules> <------------ ADDED THIS NODE
    <rule name="skipConfig" type="Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSkipRuleHandler"
          objectName="filePath" skipAction="Delete" 
          absolutePath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\myFile.whatever"/>
  </rules>
</configuration>
```

But it is still overwriting the file in question on my staging server.  I started by editing the `msdeploy.exe.config` on my dev machine and when that didn't work I updated the `msdeploy.exe.config` on my staging server as well, but again, still not working.

Am I going about this wrong?  Any suggestions on preventing this file from being overwritten?

Comment: What is getting overwritten on the staging server that you need to prevent? Have you considered setting up web.config transforms so that you can deploy your staging server settings there?

Comment: There are about 20 elements in the web.config that are being changed.  I have considered transforms, but I would rather just not copy the file.

Comment: Transforms are pretty easy and the right way to go with this. XDT is pretty straightforward too.

Comment: Ok, I'm open to that.  Just out of curiosity, why is it better to transform vs. not copy?

Comment: If you decide to change things later (or potentially don't have access to the server after deployment) you can manage it better from within the solution itself. You can also setup as many web.config transforms as you want, if you need to specify different servers.

Comment: @Dillie-O - can I use web.config transforms if I am working with a web site (rather than a web application)?

Comment: @MikeCheel/@Dillie-O, I did some poking around and the only way I found to do web.config transforms on a web site (not a web application) was this link: http://andrewtwest.com/2010/02/25/using-web-config-transformations-in-web-site-projects/  This seems like a pretty nasty hack.  After reading the article it seems like it would make more sense to simply not copy over the file, rather than trying to piece together this giant hack and explain it to future programmers.  Thoughts?

Comment: I didn't realize it was web site (vs application). I would probably go with Nathan's answer then.

Comment: I didn't realize as well. I agree with solution below.

Comment: @MikeCheel/@Dillie-O, there is no way that Nathan's answer could work with a web site project.

Comment: Why wouldnt the ExcludeFromProject thing work?

Comment: There are no project file in web site projects, so there is simply no where to add `ExludeFromProject`

Answer (score 1):

Since transforms are painful with web site projects you might be able to use this method:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx

Comment: This article is focused towards web applications and not web site projects.  What in there do you think would work in my situation?  From what I can tell his advice is to modify the project file which is impossible in my situation because web site projects do not have project files.  I do appreciate the suggestion, but I had to -1 this answer because it simply won't work for web site projects.  Please don't take it personally.

Comment: Sorry, I just tested this and you are correct there is no project file with web sites projects...  At this point I would recommend that you convert the web site project to a web application project.  I've done this before in the past and it's well documented and only took me a couple hours.  Scott Gu has a good article on how to do this...  It's also discussed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650875/exclude-files-from-web-site-publish-in-visual-studio

Comment: Ok.  Any chance you could delete this answer so I can delete the question?

Comment: I think this information could be helpful to others, so there's no harm in leaving it...

Comment: You yourself have admitted your answer does not apply to my question.  Suggesting I migrate to an entirely different project type isn't really an answer...

Comment: Sorry you feel that way Abe.  Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, what you would normally do is to have a base Web.config file, then one specific for `debug` and one specific for `release`. The debug or release portion would add/override the base one with things that are particular to this scenario. This way you can just upload both and everything will work fine.

To understand more about `web.config transformation`, please refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx