# Error while publishing project having multiple Themes

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, publish

I have a project having multiple themes in App_Themes directory, one of which is main theme and I have mentioned that in `<page>` directive of `web.config` and another theme is not being used by whole application so it's mentioned on only those pages which use that theme.

My VS has this configuration:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641
Installed Version: Professional
```

Now the issue is i'm having below error when trying to publish my web application.

```
Theme 'SecondaryTheme' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.
```

I have done some research and by few adjustments I was able to publish it at last but **why am I having this error** on first place?

Another question is: 
In adjustments I have excluded `App_Themes` from publishing ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650875/exclude-files-from-web-site-publish-in-visual-studio)), and have removed theme references from `web.config` and `pages` where it was referenced, Now of course I'll have to add those removed theme references when I will deploy my published package so it becomes a little cumbersome task to remember and do this theme reference removal and re-adding every time I do a publish. So **is there any better solution to this**?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your solution structure for theme part?

Comment: Where SecondaryTheme falls?

Comment: @Amit its LTE_CrsTheme, LTE_Themes is primary. I used secondary theme in question as just an alias to it.

Comment: So, as per given screenshotLTE_CrsTheme is not having any content because it is not showing icon to dig in?