# Exclude folder from Publish for a Website not a Web Application Project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I can't find a way to exclude folders for a Web Application Project online:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment

I can also find a way to exclude files from publish for a Website online:
[Exclude files from web site publish in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650875/exclude-files-from-web-site-publish-in-visual-studio)

And I can find ONE way to exclude folders from publish for a Website online:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1179077.aspx?Exclude+Folder+from+Website+in+Visual+Studio

The last solution says you can rename your folder by appending an underscore and Publish will ignore.

But I cannot rename my folder because there are web links that rely on that folder and system code that relies on that folder name.

**Is there any other way to exclude a folder from Publish for a Website, NOT a Web Application project?**

**Note I have a .tfignore file but Publish does not read that.

Comment: I have found the solution for this, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650875/exclude-files-from-web-site-publish-in-visual-studio/29688263#29688263

Answer (score 0):

have you tried editing the project file e.g. .csproj
and adding following line for ever file og folder that is to be excluded from publishing process.

Comment: A comment or question does not belong as an answer, also I cannot understand what you are asking, your English is unclear