# Why does Visual Studio publish packages.config too?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I use the option `Publish...` selecting as target the file system in Visual Studio 2015 it compiles the code, do the XML transformation in the *Web.config* files and copy the files to the folder I specified.

It does not copy any `*.cs` file as expected since it is compiled.

Something that I don't understand is why it publishes the *Nuget Config* file (`packages.config`), after all, the files needed are already in the `bin` folder.

I found this question that says how to **avoid** but not the **reason** they decided this file would be usable on the server.

[Can I stop VS from publishing packages.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31459951/can-i-stop-visual-studio-2012-from-ever-publishing-packages-config-and-ef-diagr)

Anyone know why `packages.config` end up in the publish folder?

Comment: Because it has `Build Action: Content`. Maybe it's default value for `*.config` files.

Comment: Think @IlyaChumakov hit the nail on the head; To visual studio, it could be another `configSource`.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov Good catch. Wonder if this was just missed or is on purpose.