# How to prevent an existing file being uploaded via Visual Studio Publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

Maybe it's a common or silly question but I didn't find any appropriate solution.

I have a JSON file located at my www-root folder, I don't want to upload this file every time I publish my website using Visual Studio.

How can I do that?

I'm using the latest build of Visual Studio 19 and ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following links. Should do the trick.

1. [Link1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/excluding-files-like-web-config-when-using-publishing-in-vs-2017)
2. [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650875/exclude-files-from-web-site-publish-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Link 1 did help actually.